# Volley on android load images already downloaded with NetworkImageView doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-volley, networkimageview

I have a function that downloaded the images in the background here is the function:

```
    @UiThread
void donwloadImage(final String url,ImageLoader mImageLoader){
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                      log.i("Download","url="+url);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null, null);
    queue.add(request);
}
```

the download works fine, but when I try to retrieve this images with a

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView 
image.setImageUrl(url,VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader());
```

with image come from xml:

```
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgArticle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

This doesn't work when I don't have network. (images already downladed with function donwloadImage(final String url,ImageLoader mImageLoader)) how can i resolve this problem ?

i use VolleySingleton:

```
package com.intescia.library.service.metier.volley;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton mInstance = null;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private VolleySingleton(Context context){
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>    
       (1000);
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mCache.get(url);
        }
    });
}

public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
    return this.mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
    return this.mImageLoader;
}
```

}

thanks for your reponses

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224520/252811

Comment: Just click on the edit link and do it your self.